# Making a custom inspector for A-Frame

Tags: aframe

Is there any guidance out there on making your own custom inspector for the A-Frame framework? Does anyone have any examples?

In A-Frame's docs it links to the Readme: "See the Inspector README for details on serving local, development, or custom builds of the Inspector."

I've been unable to find anything about custom kinds of inspectors in a-frames Github/README. I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious. If there are examples of custom inspector components, where should I find them?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Start with [inspector code base](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-inspector) to develop your own, host it somewhere and point the inspector component to it:

```
<a-scene inspector="url: your/custom/inspector/url">
```